# Why there is CGColor when we already have UIColor in IOS? If they are different then what is the difference between them?

Tags: ios, uicolor, cgcolor

I just wanted to know why there are two ways to obtain color in iOS. I am new to Swift and Objective C development, I just want to know how and why they are different?

Answer (score 6):

`CGColor` comes from a lower level than `UIColor`. This difference is not so obvious in Swift anymore, but you may see this in Objective-C where `UIColor` is an Objective-C class with methods while `CGColor` is a C type and you access it with C functions.

`UIColor` is part of the UIKit which is based on Core Graphics, where `CGColor` belongs to. While UIKit is for iOS (and tvOS), Core Graphics is for macOS and iOS, and you may share code for Core Graphics between both.

Roughly speaking, Core Graphics is for drawing while UIKit and its macOS pendant AppKit are for GUI display.

Comment: Note - `UIColor` is for iOS, tvOS, and watchOS. `CGColor` is for all of those plus macOS.

Comment: @rmaddy: Yes, you're right. I've restricted to iOS because it's the focus here.

Comment: And UIKit is used for iOS, tvOS, and watchOS.

Comment: @rmaddy: I've updated my comment. ;)

Comment: CGColor is a C struct type. UIColor is an objective-c type. That's the difference. CGColor is used by low-level graphic library.  `UIKit` just wrapped it in Objective-c for better iOS development experience.

Comment: @clemens Yes, you use WatchKit for watchOS but WatchKit uses many UIKit classes. For example, `WKInterfaceButton` uses `UIColor` when setting the button's color.

Comment: @AntiMoron: This is what I meant with "while CGColor is a C type".

Comment: @rmaddy: Indeed, how unclean.